# Detecting the size of SWFLoader content

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

This is a long shot as I don't think it's possible.

I want to load in a SWF and set it to fit in the window, whilst keeping it's aspect ratio.

When I do this by setting the height and width of the SWFLoader, the SWF will resize to best fit in the space (as it is keeping it's aspect ratio).

However I can't find a way to detect the height and width of that SWF now it has been resized. The size of the SWFLoader reflects what I set it to, and the SWFLoader.LoaderInfo size seems to be totally random.

I have also tried the loaderInfo.content, but again I don't get a value that compares to the size of the SWF I have loaded (or at lease the size of what is visible).

The only thing I can think to do is to know the height and width before and then figure out the aspect ratio, so if I resize the width to 50% of the window, I can do the maths on the height to make the swf loader the same height as it's scaled content.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup...

Just realised SWFLoader.contentHeight and contentWidth which does exactly that...